# How could i blink text in listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

How could i make a blinking text on `Listbox` item

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

ncbox = tkinter.Listbox(window, width=14, height=7, fg="blue", font=("Helvetica", 20))
ncbox.grid(row=2, column=2,columnspan=4,sticky=NW)
ncbox.insert("apple")
ncbox.insert("banana")
ncbox.insert("grape")
```

Now i want to blink apple on the listbox. how to do that?

Comment: Are you using py2 or py3?

Comment: i am using python 2.7

Comment: Sir how could i solve the problem

Comment: Even if [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) says: `The listbox can only contain text items, and all items must have the same font and color.`, apparently you can change the color (of the background or of the font) using the method `itemconfig` of your `Listbox` widget...

Answer (score -2):

You should try the following if you want to iterate over the lines in the listbox. You can't directly check for a string the listbox.

```
ncbox.get(first, last=None)
```

If this still doesn't work for you got to:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm

http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/widgets/

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the question at all, which is asking how to cause an item in the listbox to blink.